# Script freezes IE unless in Compatibility View

Tags: knockout.js, internet-explorer-9, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, kogrid

The goal is to use a grid control in a web resource on a form in CRM.  I decided on KoGrid because it could be easily bound to the knockout view model we already had in place.  The trouble is using KoGrid in a CRM context causes IE 9 to stop responding entirely.  There are no exceptions or errors logged in the console;  the only symptom is the browser locking up.

Putting the browser in compatibility mode fixes the issue, unfortunately in IE 9 doctypes are inherited so we can't control the render mode of the web resource.  Also this really just fixes the symptom and not the cause.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="../css/KoGrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../js/jquery_1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/knockout.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/koGrid_2.1.1.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .gridStyle {
            border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
            width: 400px; 
            height: 300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                debugger;
                function mainVm() {
                    var self = this;
                    this.myData = ko.observableArray([{ name: "Moroni", age: 50 },
                                                      { name: "Tiancum", age: 43 },
                                                      { name: "Jacob", age: 27 },
                                                      { name: "Nephi", age: 29 },
                                                      { name: "Enos", age: 34 }]);
                    this.gridOptions = {
                        canSelectRows: false,
                        multiSelect: false,
                        data: self.myData
                    };
                };
                ko.applyBindings(new mainVm());
            }, 3000);            
        });

    </script>

    <div class="gridStyle" data-bind="koGrid: gridOptions"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wycleffsean/yHrBA/2/

What could cause this behavior ONLY in CRM?  It works fine by itself in every browser.  What does the render mode have to do with script behavior?

Comment: It doesn't "stop responding" for me, but I do get a `SEC7112: Script from https://raw.github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid/master/koGrid-2.1.1.debug.js was blocked due to mime type mismatch` in IE9

Comment: Try actually adding that as a separate web resource and make sure that it's type is "JScript"

Comment: mismatched mime.  must be a script from france.

Comment: @thang Tat was a good one. I'm going to view a guy in striped black/white tights, black beret and white paint in his face every time I'll see anything about MIME types.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Make sure all of the CSS and JavaScript files are also web resources, or swap out the full URL hosted somewhere else.

```
<link href="../css/KoGrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../js/jquery_1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/knockout.js"></script>
<script src="../js/koGrid_2.1.1.js"></script>
```

If you do reference a CDN, make sure to use HTTPS to avoid any mixed mode authentication.

Comment: It is not an issue with a dependency.  There are no errors, and when the browser is in compatibility view it works.

Comment: I added this as an HTML web resource, added the KoGrid css and js files, and then pointed to the Microsoft CDNs and it worked fine.

Here's my header: 
[
    <link href="new_ko_grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="new_ko_grid.js"></script>
]

Comment: Bummer, the formatting took out the "https://" in front of both CDN urls.  Make sure to include those.

Comment: We were on rollup 10 at the time of this issue.  Upgrading to CRM rollup 12 seems to have resolved it